# Evee Viewport and Render Error on New Files

Tags: eevee-render-engine

this cream of a render engine has problems since i've installed 2.90.1...

Everything's all right when an old file that used evee engine is opened..

When a new General scene is opened, evee is broken. Sample screenshots are attached.. Any ideas?

OpenCL or CPU render don't differ.
All drivers up to date.
Tried a rollback install to Blender 2.83..
Radeon RX580, AMD FX 8350 Eight-Core, 32 GB Ram...

[image: Evee viewport broken]

[image: Evee viewport broken]

[image: Evee render broken]

Comment: I guess it's your graphics card: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/203615/how-to-fix-material-and-render-previews#comment342453_203615

Comment: 100% Right, thank you :) rolled back to June drivers, things are smooth..